# How change the sidebar direction to rtl in the follwing template?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use this template but I want to change its direction from right to left?

```
.body{text-align:right; float:right;}
```

but it doesn't view in the reverse direction

Comment: We can not help you without seeing the rest of the code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and revise your question

Comment: Has my answer helped you @borhanoz

Comment: I could not send the code. Show me this message:It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the direction property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

```
body{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Also, noticed that I removed the dot before the body because I am assuming your body is not a class. But you have a body tag.

```
<div class="body"></div>
```

This is the tag.

```
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `direction` property you can find the MDN documentation for it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

Use this rule on everything you want to change the direction of. Not only in the body. In fact, you can use this in child properties only without putting it in the `<body>`
Just see what you want and go for it

```css
.body {
   direction: rtl;
}
```